# NullPointerException here: This method call was *not* stubbed correctly

Tags: mongodb, scala, testing, mockito, dao

I am testing the `getDbStatus` method using Mockito in Scala. But I see the following error. Can anyone help me in this?

### Error

```
You have a NullPointerException here:
-> at com.knoldus.services.info.InfoServiceSpec$$anon$2.<init>(InfoServiceSpec.scala:50)
because this method call was *not* stubbed correctly:
-> at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
daoInstantiator.userDao();

org.mockito.exceptions.verification.SmartNullPointerException: 
You have a NullPointerException here:
-> at com.knoldus.services.info.InfoServiceSpec$$anon$2.<init>(InfoServiceSpec.scala:50)
because this method call was *not* stubbed correctly:
-> at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
daoInstantiator.userDao();
```

### InfoServiceSpec.scala

```
class InfoServiceSpec extends BaseSpec {

  trait Setup {
    val daoInstantiator: DaoInstantiator = mock[DaoInstantiator]
    val service = new InfoService(conf,daoInstantiator)(ec, logger)
  }

  "InfoService#getDbStatus" should {

    "get DbStatus" in new Setup {
      when(daoInstantiator.userDao.count(any[Filter])(any[concurrent.ExecutionContext])).thenReturn(Future(1))

      whenReady(service.getDbStatus){ result =>
        assert(result == "active")
      }
    }

  }
}
```

### InfoService.scala

```
class InfoService(config: Config, daoInstantiator: DaoInstantiator)(implicit
  val ec: ExecutionContext,
  val logger: LoggingAdapter
) {

  def getDbStatus: Future[String] = {
    var response = Future("inActive")
    val users = daoInstantiator.userDao.count(CheckActiveUsers(true))
    users.map { _ =>
      response = Future.successful("active")
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    response
  }
}
```

### DaoInstantiator.scala

```
class DaoInstantiator(database: MongoDatabase) {    
  lazy val userDao = new UserDao(database)    
}
```

Comment: The error message is precise: `daoInstantiator.userDao` is null, thus `daoInstantiator.userDao.count` causes NPE.